# _api/web/lists/ returns all the lists including system generated

Tags: rest, custom-list, office365apis

We are working on a mobile app where we want to get all the custom lists (created by user etc.).

API GET `"/_api/web/lists/"` is working perfectly fine but it is returning all the lists available in site collection, including the ones like `"Style Library"`, `"TaxonomyHiddenList"`, `"wfpub"` etc.

Is there any way to get custom lists created by users only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One property you can start to filter by is **[IsCatalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdocumentlibrary.iscatalog.aspx)**. Another one you can use is *Hidden*, although you are likely to use this on your own lists.

E.g.,

```
/_api/Web/Lists/?$filter=IsCatalog eq false
/_api/Web/Lists/?$filter=Hidden eq false
```

#### Update

Filtering out all lists seems a bit tricky, as for instance the user information list doesn't seem to have much information to filter by, except *BaseType* and *ListItemEntityTypeFullName*, but that would end up with a huge set of types to filter by (can't filter by `lt` or `gt` as one could use say BaseTemplate 101 (doclib), and 200 (Meetings) while not wanting 112 (User information list)).

But perhaps another hack can be used, at least to narrow it down a little bit more, as it turns out User information list is located in `_catalogs`, despite not being flagged as *IsCatalog*. So we could filter out all those lists, like this:

```
$expand=RootFolder
&$filter=not(substringof('/_catalogs/',RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl)) 
  and IsCatalog eq false
```

Comment: This works but only hides few lists. It's showing User Information List as well. IsHidden will also not hide some lists created by the system. So not fully accurate :)

Comment: @Akhoy I updated the answer. Feel it is not the correct approach, but for some parts it does seem to work

Comment: Is returning all the lists expected behavior by API? The problem is, I am trying to show user the lists on his / her mobile phone where he can select a list and upload his photos to that particular list.

Comment: @rahul-patil is the default yes, I think it would be bad if the API was hiding elements based on "friendlyness". If you want lists for uploading you probably want document libraries, to get only libraries try `$filter=BaseType eq 1`. To only get document libraries specifically try `$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101`, but you'd also want libraries such as Picture library, which is 109. Catalogs are libraries, so you should probably combine with my filter above

Answer (score 2):

When just looking for lists, I found a combination of [Hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.hidden.aspx) and [BaseType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasetype.aspx) gave me the best results.

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false and BaseType ne 1
```